# how to access lookup object data using mule 4 salesforce query all connector

Tags: mule, mule-studio, soql, mulesoft, mule4

I want get the lookup object data for that I have one object called Agent and another object called pincode. added lookup data field in pincode.

In Query all connector i am applying this query: select firstName__c, lastname__c, experience__c, primarycontactnumber__c, role__c, active__c, pincodeId__c, CreatedBy.FirstName, pincode.Name FROM Agent__c where active__c= true

But here i am getting error SALESFORCE:INVALID_REQUEST_DATA for pincode.Name this field. 
What is the correct query to get the pincode lookup data in the query?

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. By using select pincode__r I can get the lookup object data.
firstName__c, lastname__c, experience__c, primarycontactnumber__c, role__c, active__c, pincodeId__c, CreatedBy.FirstName, pincode__r.Name FROM Agent__c where active__c= true